# document root at /home dir for new user

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04

I have just installed a new LAMP server inside Ubuntu server. This was done using tasksel, while login as `root` user. I want to move apache document root into `/home` directory. Please advice, should i create new user other than root or just go with `root` and place the document root under eg. `/home/public_html` ?

Comment: I would prefer to create user for it. It is a weird idea for me as folder inside /home having root user ownership.